# How to use a Data Extract to send tracking activity to an SFTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, files, data-extract, sftp

I am trying to set up my first data extract activity, and I'm having a lot of trouble with the basic setup because I don't truly understand what the activities do. I'm trying to do a tracking export to send data to the Salesforce SFTP (ftp.s6.exacttarget.com) and then download it onto my machine.

From reading the Salesforce documentation, I gather that I need to set up the Data Extract first, then use a File Transfer Activity to send the file to the FTP. I've gotten those two activities to run correctly a couple of times, but each time the file I download from the FTP is still encoded and can't be read by Excel.

Another Stack Exchange question recommended using two File Transfer Activities: one to post the file to the FTP and another to unzip it. I've only gotten that to run once, and the resulting zip file was empty, and the two files inside were an empty CSV and another file with no extension.
Every other time I've tried to run these three activities in an automation, the second step fails because "File not found matching the pattern: Clicks.zip".

I'm running out of ideas. Do I need to set up some new file location? Am I doing things out of order? Am I missing a step?

1.1 Data Extract Activity Properties
[image: Data Extract Properties]

1.2 Data Extract Activity Configuration
[image: Data Extract Configuration]

2.1 Transfer File from Safehouse Properties
[image: File Transfer Properties]

2.2 Transfer File from Safehouse Configuration
[image: File Transfer Configuration]

3.1 Unzip File Properties
[image: Manage File Properties]

3.2 Unzip File Configuration
[image: Manage File Configuration]

Comment: try changing the file name in the extract to 'clicks.zip'  You should be able to DL the zipped file and extract locally as well. The unzip will push the files inside into either your default import directory or the sandbox (which would require additional file transfers)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't improve things. I still get the same error. I read that Data Extracts produced a zip file by default. Is that correct? Where does the Data Extract put the file it produces? Does it go in the Safehouse or somewhere else? I may not have the file locations set up correctly.

Comment: from my understanding it goes: compressed file created housing each extract > file moved to safehouse > moved from safehouse to ftp > unzip in ftp > extract csvs are sent to import folder or safehouse

Comment: Actually, I was wrong! I changed the Data Extract file name to Clicks.zip, but I had the Unzip step before the File Transfer in the automation. I ran the extract and the file transfer together and was able to successfully download the zip file from the FTP, download it, and decode the data. @Gortonington to the rescue again! Thanks